# Novice - create server that can store pictures and return url - iOS

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, rest, amazon-web-services

Due to Facebook api restrictions for iOS, I need to be able to send image data up to a server, for the server to store it for a short period of time (maybe an hour).  My return response should have a url to that image, which will then be posted to facebook.  I already know how to use ASIHTTPRequest and I have all the JSON code ready to go, the problem is I have NO IDEA where to even start on the server side. I don't know php.  I know this task is probably trivial, but can someone instruct me on how to do this so I don't have to spend days reading books about REST and php etc?  Do I set up an account with Amazon cloud services? Really im quite ignorant on these server matters. Im looking for something easy here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to build the web service yourself you might look into something like [Parse](https://www.parse.com/)

It's specifically designed to work with mobile apps. It also has Facebook integration.

Here's the section of their docs related to storing images https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#files-images